# Unable to remove a variable form session

Tags: php

I'm using php 4.4.4 and trying to remove an item from session array. But it doesn't remove ,additionally leaves an error.

this is how I pass id to remove from:
**page_1.php**

```
<a href="remove.php?id=<?php echo $c_id;?>">remove<?php echo $c_id;?></a>
```

this is how i remove in:
**remove.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
   $id = (int) $_GET['id']; 
   unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]); 
   $new_id=$_SESSION['items'][$id]="";
   session_write_close();
header("Location:add_cart.php?id=".$new_id);
?>
```

// the error message is as below:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

***Now manage to remove individual items form session array but the last item cannot be removed. the code is:

```
ob_start();
session_start();

$id=$_GET['id'];


unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);
```

Comment: That’s mysql error, not php error... So your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Also, you need to upgrade your PHP.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in being a newbie (we're all newbies all the time in most technologies) but it can't be an excuse to deliver code you don't understand at all, which is clearly the case here. When you aren't an expert is normal that your code flows slower or is less optimal but you must always know what it does—period.

Comment: `php 4.4.4` is really outdated (like 10 years outdated).

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the code and it works. I'm running PHP v5.5.12.

However it should work the same as in PHP v4.4.4 without any issue whatsoever.

The first thing I would do is to check within the `remove.php` file by adding the following code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
   $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
   echo $_SESSION['items'][$id];
   unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);
   echo 'Session: ' . $_SESSION['items'][$id];
   $new_id=$_SESSION['items'][$id]="";
   session_write_close();
header("Location:add_cart.php?id=".$new_id);
?>
```

I just added an extra line with an `echo` statement immediately above the `unset` function and another below the `unset` function, in order to see if it returns anything before and after the destroy.

If it doesn't basically it doesn't return anything or an error on the first `echo` then it means that the session variable you are trying to destroy doesn't even exists so it's improper to destroy a session variable which can't be located.

Also if it outputs an error but on the second line with `echo` which I've added then it means that it was basically destroyed.

This is how it is supposed to look http://screencast.com/t/sfqw3agXhqe , where "1" is the output of the `$id` variable to see that it gets catched and parsed, "Session: Valid session" is the proof that the session variable we are trying to destroy really exists and the error and "Session:" duplicated twice is the proof that it had been destroyed and PHP no longer knows what to output.

Also regarding the SQL error as the others had already stated the bug is generated in another place within your code.

Comment: I'm using a very simple way of removing items from session  and it works partly. Only the last item remain there not being able to be removed. Could you help me on this?

Comment: Is this last item that isn't able to be removed related to this topic (to this issue that you initially posted or is it another case). Can't quite understand what you are referring to, so I can provide guidance on how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Cladiu, Thanks for asking.CCurrently I'm using this code to remove items from session array.<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$id=$_GET['id'];


unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);


//header("Location:add_cart.php");
?> The problem now,this code works to remove all items in the cart except for the last one in the cart.When every item is removed from the cart,the last one still remain there not able to be removed.

Comment: Hey @ling, sorry for the delay. Theoretically it should work as it is. For some reason I think that it might be a problem of how session are registered for the items. Have you tried putting it into a `foreach`? I will further think about what could be wrong and I will let you know if anything crosses my mind.